# Extract lines selectively from blocks of lines

Tags: regex, linux, awk

Please help me with this regular expression, I need all the components from each of the first Meta Mapping.

Phrase:*.*\nMeta Mapping*.*
What would be after this? 
I just started learning regex today.

I have this so far, I am, kind of stuck. I have the document below, and the output that I want.

Main Document:

```
Phrase: "is"

Phrase: "normal."
Meta Mapping (1000):
 1000   % Normal (Mean Percent of Normal) [Quantitative Concept]
Meta Mapping (1000):
 1000   Normal [Qualitative Concept]
Meta Mapping (1000):
 1000   % normal (Percent normal) [Quantitative Concept]
Processing 00000000.tx.8: The EKG shows nonspecific changes.

Phrase: "The EKG"
Meta Mapping (1000):
 1000   EKG (Electrocardiogram) [Finding]
Meta Mapping (1000):
 1000   EKG (Electrocardiography) [Diagnostic Procedure]

Phrase: "shows"
Meta Mapping (1000):
 1000   Show [Intellectual Product]

Phrase: "nonspecific changes."
Meta Mapping (901):
 694   Nonspecific [Idea or Concept]
 861   changes (Changed status) [Quantitative Concept]
Meta Mapping (901):
 694   Nonspecific [Idea or Concept]
 861   changes (Changing) [Functional Concept]
Meta Mapping (901):
 694   Non-specific (Unspecified) [Qualitative Concept]
 861   changes (Changed status) [Quantitative Concept]
Meta Mapping (901):
 694   Non-specific (Unspecified) [Qualitative Concept]
 861   changes (Changing) [Functional Concept]
```

---

I want the result to have only one Meta Mapping for each phrase.

so

```
Phrase: "normal."
Meta Mapping (1000):
 1000   % Normal (Mean Percent of Normal) [Quantitative Concept]

Phrase: "The EKG"
Meta Mapping (1000):
 1000   EKG (Electrocardiogram) [Finding]

Phrase: "shows"
Meta Mapping (1000):
 1000   Show [Intellectual Product]

Phrase: "nonspecific changes."
Meta Mapping (901):
 694   Nonspecific [Idea or Concept]
 861   changes (Changed status) [Quantitative Concept]
```

Please help me with this regular expression, I need all the components from each of the first Meta Mapping. Thank You!

Comment: I'm glad someone provided you with a solution. As for why you received down-votes: you've shown little effort to solve the problem on your own, so your question effectively amounts to "please solve this problem for me".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this re may work for you. Just re, nothing to do with awk. Tested here [regex101.com/](http://regex101.com/)

```
Phrase.*\nMeta.*\n^((?![Meta|\n]).*\n)*
```

gnu awk version:

```
cat your_data_file | awk  '
BEGIN {
    FS="\n"
    RS="\n\n"
    OFS="\n"
}
NF > 1 {
    print $1, $2
    for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++)
        if (match($i, "Meta Mapping")) {
            print ""
            next
        }
        else
            print $i
    print ""
}
'
```

Comment: I meant negative vote. Can you not solve this with simple regex?

something like this? http://regex101.com/r/uM5jC4

Comment: +1 for the awk solution. Also, just to be explicit, your solution requires GNU `awk` or `mawk`, due to use of a multi-char. RS (which is fine on Linux; if you want your solution to be POSIX-compliant, replace `RS="\n\n"` with option `-v RS=''`, which is an `awk` idiom to break lines into records by empty lines between them).

Answer (score 0):

An annotated, POSIX-compliant `awk` solution:

```
awk -v RS='' -F'\n' -v re='^Meta Mapping \\(' '
    # Only process non-empty records:
    # those that have at least 1 "Meta Mapping" line.
  $2 ~ re { 
    print $1 # print the "Phrase: " line
    print $2 # print the 1st "Meta Mapping" line.
      # Print the remaining lines, if any, up to but not including
      # the next "Meta Mapping" line.
    for (i=3;i<=NF;++i) {
      if ($i ~ re) break # next "Meta Mapping" found; ignore and terminate block.
      print $i
    }
    print "" # print empty line between output blocks
  }
' file
```

- `RS=''` is an `awk` idiom that breaks lines into *records* by *empty lines* between them: in other words: each run of non-empty lines forms a single record.
- `-F'\n'` breaks each record into *fields* by *lines*; i.e., `$1` refers to the 1st line in each record, `$2` to the 2nd, ...; `NF` contains the number of lines (fields) in the current record.
- `re='...'` defines an `awk` variable containing a regular expression that identifies the `Meta Mapping` lines in each record.